# How can I invert the colors of a picture, without changing the values in colorbar in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, graphics, matlab-figure, color-mapping

I'm plotting a confusion matrix as the following with colorbar in it:

[image]

What I would like to do now is keep everything exactly the same, but inverse the colors. I have tried the following code (which I read from another post in SOF):

```
myimage = sum(255 - myimage, 3);
```

And this gives me:

[image]

And this is exactly what I want, with the exception that the values in the colorbar have changed...How can I do the same thing without changing the values in the colorbar?

Thank you for any help =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

why wont you just invert the colormap by flipping up-down (`flipud`)? For example:

```
cmap=flipud(colormap(gray));
colormap(cmap);
```

or in a more compact way:

```
imagesc(your_image);
colormap(flipud(gray))
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer =) I didn't know about that, excellent! Worked like a charm.